# One liner to remove all occurrences of sub-strings in array with filter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The title pretty much explains the question. I'd like to filter through an array and remove all occurrences of substrings. Similiar to how can be done by matching entire strings to remove like this

```
const x = ["don't delete", "delete", "delete", "don't delete", "delete", "don't delete"]
x= x.filter(i => i !== 'delete me');

> console.log(x)
["don't delete", "don't delete", "don't delete"]
```

So let's say I want to just remove all the occurances of `'` so every `don't` becomes `dont`, or maybe I just want to remove the every `don't` all together. I know you can match substrings with `includes()` but not sure how to implement it with a filter.

How could I go about this in a one liner? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So let's say I want to just remove all the occurances of ' so every
>   don't becomes dont

use `map` function instead of `filter`

```js
const x = ["don't delete", "delete", "delete", "don't delete", "delete", "don't delete"]
const toRemove = "'";

const res = x.map(i => (i.includes(toRemove) ? i.replace(toRemove, '').trim() : i));

console.log(res)
```

> or maybe I just want to remove the every don't all together

use `map` function along with `filter` function

```js
const x = ["don't delete", "delete", "delete", "don't delete", "delete", "don't delete"]
const toRemove = "'";

const res = x.map(i => i.split(' ').filter(w => !w.includes(toRemove)).join(' '));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following way using `includes()`:

```js
const x = ["don't delete", "delete", "delete", "don't delete", "delete", "don't delete"]
var y = x.filter(i => i.includes("don't"));

console.log(y);
```

**Please Note:** *The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.*

Comment: OP wants to remove all occurrences of a sub-string, you are just filtering the strings that contain the sub-string.

Comment: @Yousaf, I think OP has mentioned the expected *output* for the given *input* in the question.

Comment: output mentioned doesn't matches the description of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you can do:

```js
const x = ["don't delete", "delete", "delete", "don't delete", "delete", "don't delete"]
  .filter(i => i.includes("don't")).map(s => s.replace("'", ""));

console.log(x);
```

So using a `map()` after the `filter()` will do the job.

Comment: And, [as Mamun mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62101569/13647196), your `const x` can't be reassigned, either declare it `let` or (probably the best option) directly assign to your `x` the result of the one-liner.

Comment: Handy that you can almost use `i.includes()` as a way to narrow down the search before replacing. For my case that I didn't mention in the post is I only really need to replace a substring that consists inside every index of the array.